# Poor performance on Oracle DB with large-ish dataset

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working with a legacy Oracle table containing roughly 30 columns and 1.5 billion rows. It contains sales data from the past two years. The table has indexes on SALES_DATE, CLIENT_ID and PRODUCT_ID. I regularly need to find out the value of the sales for a specific client's specific products between two dates. The queries I usually run are of the type:

```
select sum(SALES_VALUE) 
from SALES 
where CLIENT_ID = 9999 
  and PRODUCT_ID IN (1, 2, 15, 16) 
  and SALES_DATE between to_date('2015-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
                     and to_date('2015-02-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

A single run for this query can often take up to half an hour (even with a relatively short date span chosen), and I am struggling to understand why. Is there anything particularly inefficient about the query itself, or is it more likely due to performance issues in the database itself?
I have very limited powers to change the database itself, but am free to write my own queries. What can I do to improve performance here?

Thanks in advance,
osf

EDIT:
We are using Oracle Database 11g 11.2.0.1.0.
Here are the results of the Explain Plan:

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name          | Rows  | Bytes | Cost  | Pstart| Pstop |    TQ  |IN-OUT| PQ Distrib |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |               |     1 |    20 | 11189 |       |       |        |      |            |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                        |               |     1 |    20 |       |       |       |        |      |            |
|   2 |   PX COORDINATOR                       |               |       |       |       |       |       |        |      |            |
|   3 |    PX SEND QC (RANDOM)                 | :TQ10000      |     1 |    20 |       |       |       |  Q1,00 | P->S | QC (RAND)  |
|   4 |     SORT AGGREGATE                     |               |     1 |    20 |       |       |       |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   5 |      PX PARTITION RANGE ALL            |               |   157 |  3140 | 11189 |     1 |   160 |  Q1,00 | PCWC |            |
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| SALES         |   157 |  3140 | 11189 |     1 |   160 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
|   7 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                | IX_SALES_DATE |   295K|       |   703 |     1 |   160 |  Q1,00 | PCWP |            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Please follow the steps in this post https://community.oracle.com/thread/503834?tstart=0 and post them with your question

Comment: Yeah; we'll need to know a fair bit more. As well as everything else people have mentioned, what Oracle version are you on? And are you sure this is really your job to be doing? If you only have limited access to the database, that suggests there's a DBA team somewhere that should be doing this kind of analysis and tuning for you.

Comment: 1.5 billion rows sounds like maybe a candidate for partitioning.  https://docs.oracle.com/html/A96524_01/c12parti.htm

Comment: Maybe will be better use index on CLIENT_ID, not on SALES_DATE

Comment: Can you paste completed DDL of table and all indexes?

Comment: @user1516873 better way is use one composit index [SALES_DATE, CLIENT_ID, PRODUCT_ID]. But need to know selectivity on each fields and their combination to recommend.

Comment: @Stawros table contain 1.5 billion rows, index on sales_date hits 300K, it is ~1/5 of all records. Index on CLIENT_ID will be more selective that index on SALES_DATE if OP has more that 5 clients. Sure i am not a oracle expert, and can be wrong, that why i write a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @user1516873 By one CLIENT_ID may contains 100K rows (its this may be an organization) - and selectivity still poor, but combination CLIENT_ID + PRODUCT_ID + SALES_DATE can return tens of rows - selectivity much better. And a phrase "table has indexes on SALES_DATE, CLIENT_ID and PRODUCT_ID" mean that table has index on CLIENT_ID.

Answer (score 1):

The SUM requires that the database read and process all rows which satisfy the query criteria before presenting the result, and it appears that the optimizer believes the most limiting criteria is SALES_DATE. It also appears that the table is partitioned on SALES_DATE, which may also be affecting the optimizer's decision.

First, make sure that the table's statistics are up-to-date by executing

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('YOUR_SCHEMA', 'SALES');
END;
```

You may have to get a DBA to run this for you. Hopefully statistics are already being gathered on your tables on a regular basis, so check with your DBAs. You can find out when stats where last gathered by executing

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, LAST_ANALYZED
  FROM USER_TABLES
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SALES'
```

If this has been a while (more than a few days) or if this is a high-activity table more frequent statistics collection may be warranted.

As has been mentioned in a comment above, it's likely that in order to improve performance you're going to need to add an index. You could add an index on (SALES_DATE, CLIENT_ID, PRODUCT_ID) but that would still require the database to read the actual data row after it's scanned the index, doubling the needed I/O's, which could tip the optimizer to doing a table scan - so if you're being pragmatic you'd make the index (SALES_DATE, CLIENT_ID, PRODUCT_ID, SALES_VALUE) which allows the optimizer to get all the data it needs for the query without ever reading the actual data in the row. This is a pragmatic solution for improving performance, but may (trivially) slow INSERTs and UPDATEs.

Best of luck.